# Increasing Transfer Speeds from External HDDs

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive, usb-3

I've a 500 GB USB 3.0 External HDD which is half used (265 GB is used; total formatted capacity is ~460 GB). When I transfer files from that to my laptop's HDD (5400 RPM) via the USB Type-A 3.0 port, I get a max speed of around 100 MB/s. But the average speed while transferring large folders (~40 GB) is ~20 MB/s. It even reached 100-500 KB/s when transferring the last file I copied into it! [MB/s = Mega BYTE per second]

I think that it has to do with where the data is actually stored in the Hard Drive, so will I have to create partitions in it to mark sectors with different speeds or the HDD is smart enough to store the data on the faster sectors first and on the slower sectors later?

Also, can the CPU bottle-neck the transfer speeds if it's a dual-core or something? I've a quad-core Ryzen 2500u in a thermally cool chassis.

My HDD: Toshiba DTB305 5V⎓1A (5W) USB 3.0 Micro-B  to Type-A

On [Toshiba's website](https://www.toshiba-storage.com/products/toshiba-portable-hard-drives-canvio-basics/), they mention max. transfer rate of ~5 Gbit/s (~625 MB/s). Can I ever get that even for 10E-100 picoseconds?

On [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00N2S73UC) (Not sure if this one is DTB305 but it looks the same), I found that it's a 5400 RPM Drive.

I don't want to buy an External SSD as I rarely use my eHDD.

Comment: USB at ~5 Gbit/s is not ~625 MB/s but only 500 MB/s, since data encoding is 8b/10b, each byte takes 10 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is unrelated to transfer speed - it is a product of **access latency**.

(Nearly) every file write needs two disk seeks (around 15ms each on a 5400RPM disk), and if you transfer many small files these seek times will easily outweigh the time needed to transfer the actual content. If you transfer one big unfragmented file, you will get close to the natural transfer speed of the disk, which should be around 100 MB/s.

This is exactly the reason, why SATA SSDs are so fast subjectively eben on a SATA2 port - while their transfer speeds may just be 2-3 times those of a disk, their access times are thousands of times faster.

Seek speed is an intrinsic property of your disk, so there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: The biggest contributor to seek time is rotational speed - so there are no "good" sectors

Answer (score 1):

CPU will almost never come into play in raw IO. You have two 5400 RPM drives; this is significantly less than optimal. I don't think the USB3.0 will be a limiting factor in this instance. How the data on the drive is oriented is not very relevant, but if the data is fragmented, defragment it.

Other than a possible defrag, you are pretty much stuck with performance without replacing the hard drives (especially the external).